# Is there a shortcut to change color of 2 children in css?

Tags: html, css, children

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
        <li>li 1</li>
        <li>li 2</li>
        <li>li 3
            <ol>This is another list 1</ol>
            <ol>This is another list 2</ol>
            <ol>This is another list 3</ol>
            <ol>This is another list 4</ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

with the following css:

```
ul li{
    background-color: violet;
}

ul li ol:nth-child(3){
    background-color:aquamarine;
}
```

my question is, is there a way to change the color of children 3 and 1 other than add

```
ul li ol:nth-child(1){
    background-color:aquamarine;
}
```

Comment: as a side note, your code is not valid, <ol> should have nested list-item as children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ol:nth-child(odd)` or calculation (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child))

Other then that you can group them if you need particular ones:
`ul li ol:nth-child(3), ol:nth-child(1)`